# Argument 1 passed t be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Why am I getting the following error?

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance 
of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in 
app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Auth/AuthController.php on line 72 and defined
```

**Functions:**

```
protected function loginValidation($request)
    {
        $rules = array(
          'fname' => 'required|max:255',
          'lname'  => 'required|max:255',
          'email'      => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
          'password'   => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    );
        $this->validate( $request , $rules);
    }
  protected function getLoginCredentials(Request $request)
  {
    $validator = $this->loginValidation(Request::all());

    var_dump($validator); die();

    if($validator->passes())
    {
    return[
    'email'    => Request::input('email'),
    'password' => Request::input('password'),
    'type'     => 1  
    ];

    return true;
    }else{
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors();
    }
  }
```

**Updated Code:**

```
public function validate($request, $rules)
    {
        $rules = array(
          'fname' => 'required|max:255',
          'lname'  => 'required|max:255',
          'email'      => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
          'password'   => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    );
        $this->validate( $request , $rules);
    }



protected function getLoginCredentials(Request $request)
  {
    $validator = $this->validate($request, $rules);

    if($validator->passes())
    {
    return[
    'email'    => Request::input('email'),
    'password' => Request::input('password'),
    'type'     => 1  
    ];

    return true;
    }else{
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors();
    }
  }
```

**Error:**

```
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\AuthController::validate() should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array)
```

Comment: can you show the validate function

Comment: @oseintow its loginValidation thats there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to

```
 $validator = $this->loginValidation($request);
```

With this you pass an instance of Request to the validate function

you are passing an array to the first argument of the validate function which i guess should be an instance of Request

```
$this->validate( $request , $rules);
```

### Updated

```
protected function loginValidation($request)
{
    $rules = array(
      'fname' => 'required|max:255',
      'lname'  => 'required|max:255',
      'email'      => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
      'password'   => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
);
    $this->validate( $request , $rules);
}

protected function getLoginCredentials(Request $request)
{
   $validator = $this->loginValidation($request);

   var_dump($validator); die();

   if($validator->passes())
   {
     return[
      'email'    => Request::input('email'),
      'password' => Request::input('password'),
      'type'     => 1  
  ];

      return true;
   }else{
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors();
   }
}
```

Comment: But then what would I do with the $this->validate( $request , $rules); in the login function when I rename it to validate?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie - the same thing that you're currently doing. The error message is just saying that you need to pass that function the full Request object, not the results of the Request::all() method.

Comment: Thanks now I get an error of: Undefined variable: rules

Comment: line number and file

Comment: @JessMcKenzie is your code still exactly the same as above, but you've replaced loginValidation(Request::all()) with  loginValidation($request) ?

Comment: @oseintow     $validator = $this->validate($request, $rules);

Comment: @JessMcKenzie and it's not a typo error? You use $rules both to define your array variable and in your validate($request, $rules) call? No missing dollar sign or spelling mistake (sorry, but got to ask)?

Comment: @Ambulare I have just updated my question with the code and new error

Comment: You shouldnt have changed loginValidation to validate. What you've done now will end in an endless recursion

Comment: am updating my answer to be how it should be

Comment: Anytime @Jess Mckenzie